# Default font size of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Anybody knows the default font size of UITableViewCell?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  Sure, there's "RTFM", but it is a legitimate question.  The OP didn't mention where/how he/she looked, I guess that's what I'd say is wrong with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle font size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775107/uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-font-size)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This [question was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775107/uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-font-size) by [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137350/vladimir).

Here's what he said:

> You can always set any font to those labels in code so if you want some guaranteed fixed values  you'd better do that as size values may vary depending on many factors (cell's style, sdk version, os version etc).
>
> I've tested on simulator with 4.2 SDK version and got following results (no extra properties were set for cells):
>
> 1. **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle:**
>
>    textLabel: Helvetica Bold, size: labelFontSize+1 (18 px)
>
>    detailsLabel: Helvetica, size: systemFontSize (14 px)
> 2. **UITableViewCellStyleValue1:**
>
>    textLabel: Helvetica Bold, size: labelFontSize (17 px)
>
>    detailsLabel: Helvetica Bold, size: systemFontSize+1 (15 px)
> 3. **UITableViewCellStyleValue2:**
>
>    textLabel: Helvetica Bold, size: smallSystemFontSize (12 px)
>
>    detailsLabel: Helvetica, size: labelFontSize (17 px)

[Default UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775107/uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-font-size)

Answer (score 19):

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
```

Which was discovered by changing the font of a `UITableViewCell`'s `textLabel` until it matched the default.

Comment: Dave should know, he can literally open Xcode and look at the source of UITableViewCell...

Answer (score 9):

If you look in the documentation for `UIFont` there are methods for retrieving system font sizes. I'd say they'll have you're answer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

`+ labelFontSize` is probably the one you're after.

Comment: example of use is [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

Answer (score 0):

The font for the text label is now:

```
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
```