# What are the default font settings used in the UITableViewCell styles?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Anyone have a listing of the default font settings Apple uses in the UITableViewCells, UILabel etc? Also the positioning information for the textLabel in the UITableViewCell both grouped and plain would be fantastic.

Comment: Check my answer on similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775107/uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-font-size/4777507#4777507.

Comment: to check label positioning just create sample project and check what cell's labels frames are. They will probably depend on many factors (e.g. cell size) and probably may be changed in future,so you should not rely on those values anyway.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the answer. What is the code you use to check frames for UIViews? Do you know if there is a comparable call that will tell you font color and size?

Comment: you can get font color from label's textColor property, font sizes I found manually - just experimenting with them. about frames - I have not tried that yet, will do when have free time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you familiar with the debugger?  It knows all.  To get access to the layout, try the following in gdb.

I set the breakpoint in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is called right before the cell is displayed

(note: there's a background image in my cell)

```
(gdb) po cell
<UITableViewCell: 0x59e9920; frame = (0 66; 320 44); text = '396 Studio'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x59e9a00>>

(gdb) po [cell subviews]
<__NSArrayM 0x4eaf730>(
 <UIImageView: 0x59ea660; frame = (0 0; 320 100); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x59ea690>>,
 <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x59e9eb0; frame = (9 0; 302 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x59ea070>>
)

(gdb) po [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews]
<__NSArrayM 0x4eaf700>(
 <UILabel: 0x59e9170; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = '396 Studio'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x59e91e0>>,
 <UITableViewLabel: 0x59e65c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'Houston'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x59e6690>>
)


(gdb) po [0x59e9170 font]
<UICFFont: 0x5e12610> font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 0px


(gdb) p (CGRect)[cell frame]
$1 = {
  origin = {
    x = 0, 
    y = 66
  }, 
  size = {
    width = 320, 
    height = 44
  }
}
```

`po` = print object
`p` = print, but you have to cast the value to the type you know it is

no property access `cell.frame` - use objective-c methods `[cell frame]`

Also, here is a 4 year old, but still useful article on iPhone fonts: [daring fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts).

Comment: This was useful up to the point that the debugger reports the font-size is zero. At what point is the *real* font-size determined?

Comment: you might try subclassing `UITableViewCell`, overriding an important display method to just call `super` and inspect the values then

Comment: Cool...didn't know about the debugger terminal

Answer (score 7):

I subclassed a UITableViewCell to get these values. Heres my code:

```
  dlog(@"%@",self.detailTextLabel.font);
  dlog(@"%@",self.detailTextLabel.bounds);
  dlog(@"%f",self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
  dlog(@"%f",self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width);
  dlog(@"%f",self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x);
  dlog(@"%f",self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y);
  dlog(@"%@",self.detailTextLabel.textColor);
```

output:

```
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.384 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(48)> <UICFFont: 0x68c8b20> font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px//remember the text will shrink before hiding some with the "..." but this is default
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.387 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(49)> (null)
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.389 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(50)> 18.000000
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.391 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(51)> 280.000000//its 284 if there is no accessory view(such as the checkmark I had in there when this ran)
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.393 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(52)> 10.000000
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.396 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(53)> 24.000000
  2012-06-06 15:01:08.398 myapp[1007:f803] <mytablecell.m:(54)> UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.5 0.5 0.5 1
```