# iOS UITableView dynamic width

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize

I have a UITableView with cells that have basic strings in them. At the moment I have my table's frame hard set to a width of 400. What I was wondering is if there was a way to adjust the frame based on the longest word in the row. I tried to get my cells textLabel value, but they are always returning null. I have tried to search online for any help, but I've only seen references on changing the height.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource (which is usually the UITableViewController) can be the one to compute the maximum width of any string that it provides to the UITableView. At that point the datasource can modify the UITableView's frame and this should activate the reload mechanism of the UITableView. Thanks to [NSString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) computing the maximum width of a string is easy. Also take care to set a limit to the width of the table by specifying a maximum width (you mentioned 400).

```
    CGFloat maxWidth = 0.0;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(400,99999);
    CGFloat cellIndent = 0; //Use this to account for any cell indenting
    for(NSString * text in datasource.array){

        CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:yourFont 
                                      constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        maxWidth = MAX(maxWidth,textSize.width + 2.0*cellIndent);
    }

   //Now change the tableView's frame
   CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;
   newFrame.size.width = maxWidth;
   tableView.frame = newFrame;

   //I don't believe a table reload is necessary let me know
   [tableView reloadData];
```

You should also think about how the table view will be positioned after you make the change to the width. Since the frame's origin was never modified the table view's top left corner will remain in the same position but it will grow towards the right.

Comment: How would I get the font and linebreak from the table? I only ask because I set the cell using UITableViewCellStyleDefault

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775107/uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-font-size) shows a very good guess of what the UIFont is but if I were you I would specifically set a UIFont for my table cells so you would know for sure. I'm certain that the default line break mode for the default table cells are UILineBreakModeTailTruncation.